# Some clarity about HPV

Tags: hpv, warts, genital-warts

I have experienced two separate episodes of HPV as warts in my body; the fist one was on my foot sole, the second in my genital area. I had the one in my foot for months until it got inflamed due to too much standing and I had it removed in ten days with vinegar. I did the same treatment with the genital one, same outcome. I do not know how effective is acid on the virus. Certainly acid deteriorates the whole epithelial environment facilitating wart detachment. It would be interesting to extend this discussion also to the effects of acid on the virus. But this in not what I want to know. My questions are: is the virus limited to the area where it overtly manifest itself (warts) or once you get infected the virus spreads everywhere in your body? Was I free from the virus once I removed the wart?

> HPV infection is limited to the basal cells of stratified epithelium, the only tissue in which they replicate.[95] The virus cannot bind to live tissue; instead, it infects epithelial tissues through micro-abrasions or other epithelial trauma that exposes segments of the basement membrane.[95]  (From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_papillomavirus_infection#Hands)

It seems the virus in limited to the skin.
It is rarely heard of HPV manifesting in different areas other than hands, feet and genitalia. Any particular reason? Does the immune system keep it limited to those areas?

My next question would have been: is there a cure?

> There is currently no specific treatment for HPV infection.[162][163][164] However, the viral infection, more often than not, clears to undetectable levels by itself.[165] According to the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention, the body's immune system clears HPV naturally within two years for 90% of cases (see Clearance subsection in Virology for more detail).[162] However, experts do not agree on whether the virus is completely eliminated or reduced to undetectable levels, and it is difficult to know when it is contagious.[166] (From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_papillomavirus_infection#Hands)

I guess we have the answer...

Quick excerpt about effects of disinfectants. No acids are mentioned.

> The virus is unusually hardy, and is immune to most common disinfectants. It is the first virus ever shown to be resistant to inactivation by glutaraldehyde, which is among the most common strong disinfectants used in hospitals.[156] Diluted sodium hypochlorite bleach is effective,[156] (From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_papillomavirus_infection#Hands)

What tests are used to detect HPV?

Comment: It seems like you have multiple questions here, rather than one.

Comment: Please, consider the first question you come across as the relevant one. If the thread is too broad then delete the rest or point it out

Comment: Putting aside the proper diagnosis and treatment of the genital warts by a doctor (which a person should do), then it would not be a bad idea to increase pterostilbene in the diet by eating such things as cranberries, blueberries, grapes, also depending on where one lives, a safe, quality product of Pterocarpus marsupium. No need to go overboard. If a person takes any supplements they should inform their doctor and get their advice on it.

Comment: I had the one on my foot around 2011 and the genital one 4 year ago. I haven't experienced anything else anywhere after I treated them (I even got rid of a couple of moles after. The method seems to be somehow effective). Hence my questions. Is the virus gone or has my immune system been strong enough to nicely keep the virus at bay? Anyways, soon or later I'll pay a visit to my GP. He should know which tests are currently used to detect HPV and who knows even give me some more info about the virus.